# PostgreSQL query for getting last numeric digit in a string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to SQL and attempting to create a query for PostgreSQL that deals with the following cases:

- I have a column with string data type.
- The strings in this column can be up to 11 digits long, but there are some records that only contain 6 or 7 digits. I only need to consider these records.
- In both cases, I need to find the last numeric digit and count the occurrences of this digit. For example, if I have the values 'BBB0123' and 'AA123A' on the column, the count of the digit '3' would be 2.
- Additionally, records with 7 digits have this structure: 'BBB0123' where the last numeric digit is at the end of the string. For records with 6 digits, the structure is like this: 'AA123A' where the last numeric digit is in the penultimate position of the string.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case expression` for extracting the appropriate digit, then wrap your query with a count.

```
create table table1 (
  id varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into table1 values 
('AA123A'), 
('AA133B'), 
('AB456C'),
('AAA0123'), 
('DDD1236'), 
('DEF6521'), 
('ABC123ABC');
```

---

```
select id2, count(*)
from (
select 
 id, 
 case
  when length(id) = 7 then right(id, 1)
  when length(id) = 6 then substring(id, 5, 1)
 end as id2
from table1
where length(id) in (6, 7)
  )z
group by id2
order by id2;
```

| id2 | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9jmpcaa68cyhau7BMUXGUi/1)